# binary invert values of bytearray

Tags: python, operators

I want to invert (flip bits; binary not) all values of a bytearray. I tried this:

```
for index in xrange(len(data)):
    data[index] = ~data[index]
```

This fails because p.ex. 0 gets -1 and then:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    data[index] = ~data[index]
ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could XOR each value with a bitmask of all ones:

```
data[index] ^= 0b11111111
```

Alternatively:

```
data[index] ^= 0xFF
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to mask off the higher-order/sign bits that Python creates when you do the bitwise inversion (e.g., in Python, `~0xff` is -256, not the zero that a C programmer would expect.)

```
>>> b = bytearray((0x00, 0x55, 0xAA, 0xFF))
>>> b
bytearray(b'\x00U\xaa\xff')
>>> for i, v in enumerate(b):
...    b[i] = 0xFF & ~v
...
>>> b
bytearray(b'\xff\xaaU\x00')
```